# Photo app that allows zooming in as a focus tool

Tags: android, ios, photography, mobile

Is there any photo app for a telephone that allows me to zoom in to check the focus more accurately, but will still capture the entire photo from the sensor, not just the part that is on the screen at the time of the capture?

I would like to use this feature for close-up photography. I find it hard to find the minimum focus distance without it.

I use IOS, but suggestions for other phones are also welcome because they are useful for other people.

Answer (score 2):

According to the web site the app [Pro Camera](https://apps.shopmoment.com/pro-camera) by Moment support manual focus and focus peaking which is something you can use to keep focus in macro. What I see at the moment the app is for iOS. Also it support "shoot in Raw mode and select from HEIF, HEVC, TIFF, and JPEG" according to [dpreview](https://www.dpreview.com/news/2691596339/moment-launches-camera-app-with-focus-on-manual-control).

N.B. No affiliation with any of the manufacturers/websites. And I did not test the app.

Comment: As a suggestion, actually providing the name of the app would slightly improve the answer.

Comment: @EricS Isn't the name of the app "Pro camera?"